# Fixed textframes in MigraDoc?

Tags: migradoc

I wrote a very simple drag and drop style report screen online so users can specify labels and fields etc much like an MS Access Report.  I am having an issue getting this to output as PDF and I am using MigraDoc.  The TextFrame allows you to specify a Left/Top which is good but I need to do this for multiple rows and I can't quite get it to work in this way.

At present I tried to add a table and a row (for each record) and put textframes within this with the left/top properties but every field gets put in the same place i.e. 0,0 and the records flow over both the header and footer?

I am using c#

Comment: I don't understand why you put Textframes into the table cells. Table cells grow with their contents - and if tables get too large, tables will break to the next page (table cells will not break so make sure not to put too much into one cell). For complete layout control, you can still use PDFsharp (included with MigraDoc).

Comment: Because I needed to set a height of an area for each record as it can be changed by the user and I used MigraDoc purposely because I wanted it to break to the next page which PdfSharp doesn't seem to do (unless I missed how), I have to calculate if the current record writing to the pdf will go off the page and go to a new one if so.

Imagine a report of a list of contacts that is several pages long, for each record the user has specified the exact top/left position it will go.  I only did this as a test if there is a better way to accomplish this then please tell me.